# Drawing using accelerometer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to do a project that is basically a remake of the already
posted apps on the AppStore namely movosity and air paint.
Can anybody give me an idea as to what approach should I take? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could base your program on [the elephant who paints](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=He7Ge7Sogrk), and call it ProboscisPainter or some such.  I'm not sure how many elephants are using iPhones (since they tend to prefer Verizon), but you could extend it to humans by encouraging strapping the phone to whatever dangling appendage people have handy.  And if you stick to alliteration, your program will name itself.